# I want to fetch the list of users who voted for a specific link

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show the list of users who voted for specific link like list of users who voted for link 1..etc i get the count of votes on every link but i cant figure out how to fetch the users.

Link Model:

```
   /**
    *
    *links votes with respect to users
    *@return 
    */
    public function votes(){

        return $this->hasMany(Communitylinkvotes::class,'community_links_id');
    }

    // practise

    public function userss(){

        return $this->hasMany(Communitylinkvotes::class,'user_id','community_links_id');
    }
```

CommunityLinkVotes model or Pivot table model

```
class Communitylinkvotes extends Model
{
    //

    protected $table = 'community_links_votes';
}
```

Migration for votes

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('community_links_votes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->index();
            $table->integer('community_links_id')->index();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did you intentionally name your function `userss()` rather than `users()`?

Comment: yes thats for testing because users() already exists with purpose of which user create this link.

Comment: Where are you retrieving your votes from? could you post your code, please?

Comment: have a look at the votes method..!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  public static  function get_voted_users($id){

        $result = DB::select(
            DB::raw('SELECT users.name FROM users join community_links_votes on community_links_votes.user_id = users.id 
                join community_links on community_links.id = community_links_votes.community_links_id 
                where community_links.id = '.$id.'  ')
        );

        return $result;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifically trying to get the list of users by starting with the Link model?

If not, do something like this:

```php
User::whereHas('votes', function($query) use ($some_id) {
    $query->where('community_links_id', $some_id);
})->get();
```

If so, I think your users relationship on the Link model needs to be a `hasManyThrough`.
Something like:

```php
$this->hasManyThrough(User::class,Communitylinkvotes::class);
```

Comment: yes i m starting with link model like if admin click on the link i want to display all the users name who voted for that link and hasManyThrough is not working

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [belongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship. That will be easy to get what you are trying to get. Add relationship to your `Communitylink` Model.

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'community_links_votes','user_id', 'community_links_id');
        //community_links_votes is the pivot table  
    }
```

Controller:

```
$link = Communitylink::find(1);
```

And now you can get the users for that link like below example in blade:

```
@foreach($link->users as $user)
    {{ $user->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: not giving the correct output like for link id=14 there is a one vote in database but it shows me 0 or no user

Comment: check that id does exists in database.

Comment: yes it exists even for link id=1 which have 3 votes from different users it just showing only 1

Comment: follow the instructions correctly from the documentationn. you are missing something that's giving wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

Some improvements to controller and view compared to @emon...let me know either it is working or not..

```
public function users()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 
'community_links_votes','user_id', 'community_links_id');
    //community_links_votes is the pivot table  
    }
```

Controller:

```
$link = Communitylink::with('users') - >first();

And now you can get the users for that link like below 
example in blade:

@foreach($link->users as $user)
{{ $user->first() - >name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: not wokring just showing one user but there are 3 users who voted for the same link

Comment: See my edits and i hope it will work... If not so do a dd() and let me see what happens

Comment: actually your code is working fine like @emon but it only shows first user who voted for that link but there are total 3 users who voted for that same link if i miss something then why it keep showing one user...!!!!

Comment: Try using the first() instead of get()... Or see me edits into controller..

Comment: none of the solution is working so i came up with RAW query and everything working fine thanks for your time